# Entity Framework Update from List Of class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have below table CustEntry:-

```
CustID CustName CustAddress AddedBy DateAdded CustStatus
```

Within this table I have many records.

I am using EF6
From entityframework I want to update only 2 columns of all table records.

For that I have class structure as :-

```
class CustEntry
{
    public string CustName {get;set;}
    public string CustStatus {get;set;}
}
class RootCustEntry
{
    public List<CustEntry> CustEntry{ get; set; }
}
```

Note :- I have to update only CustName and CustStatus comming to me through List CustEntry from RootCustEntry object

How can I bulk update the records without using foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I bulk update the records without using foreach loop?

Unfortunately, this is not supported in Entity Framework out of the box.

However, you can use the batch update functionality in the [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended) (Not supported since 2015 as stated on their github).

So you can check out this [EntityFramework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/?z=ef-extended) (Recomended by the creators of EntityFramework.Extended, as stated on their github).

[Batch Update Example code of EntityFramework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update)

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.

// UPDATE all users inactive for 2 years
var date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2);
ctx.Users.Where(x => x.LastLoginDate < date)
         .UpdateAsync(x => new User() { IsSoftDeleted = 1 });
```

PS: If you do not want to use 3rd party libraries then you can write a [stored procedure](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/CRUD-using-stored-procedures.aspx)